# Is using a passive voice as a subject of another passive voice allowed?

Tags: passive-voice

Is it correct to use this sentence:

All efforts that have been made (by someone) probably won't be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think your title accurately describes your sentence. It is more idiomatic to say "None of these will be" than "All of these won't be". So "None of the efforts made (by someone) are likely to be appreciated" is idiomatic. Or "None of (someone's) efforts are likely to be appreciated." The **form** of your sentence - like "The meal that was cooked wasn't eaten" - is perfectly OK!

Comment: I would suggest the inclusion of an article before effort is more normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voice of your sentence is fine, but there are other issues with it that prevent it from scanning.

Remember that "won't" is a contraction of "will not", and we tend not to use "all.... not".

For example:

> <s>All the bananas are not ripe</s> - *wrong*
> **None** of the bananas are ripe - *right*

You could instead say:

- Probably *none* of the efforts made were appreciated.
- All the efforts made were probably *unappreciated*.